# Format double with swprintf_s and send to OutputDebugStringW

Tags: c++, windows

I have problem formatting a double for printout in the debug Window. I have tried to use swprintf_s function and the %d, the value is 0.804 but its not working at all.

[image]

I get value 65384... How shall i improve this code?

```
void MyOutputFunction(const wchar_t *format, double args)
{  
  wchar_t buf[2048];    
  swprintf_s(buf, _countof(buf), format, args);
  OutputDebugStringW(buf);
}
```

Comment: [This `swprintf_s` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwprintf) might be useful. Read the format descriptions, because `"%d"` is not used for floating point values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **`%f`** (*not* `%d`) as format specifier for `double`s.